# LINQ to NHibernate query only returning last matching item, not all matching items

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-nhibernate

This LINQ query should return all Recipes having a RecipeLineItem whose Ingredient title equals "Chocolate." Unfortunately, my query is only returning the **last** Recipe that matches my criteria, not **all** Recipes that match my criteria.

The problem query:

```
var recipesWithChocolateAsAnIngredient =
        session.Query<Recipe>()
            .Select(r => r)
            .Where(r => r.RecipeLineItems
                .Any(i => i.Ingredient.Title == "Chocolate"));
```

Here are my (simplified) objects:

```
public class Recipe
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IList<RecipeLineItem> RecipeLineItems { get; set; }
}

public class RecipeLineItem
{
    public Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; }
}

public class Ingredient
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: FYI, I just tried switching the WHERE/SELECT clauses around, but it didn't fix my problem. 

`var recipesWithChocolateAsAnIngredient =      session.Query<Recipe>().Where(r => r.RecipeLineItems.Any(i => i.Ingredient.Title == "Chocolate")).Select(r => r);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, problem solved. **Short explanation: the LINQ query works fine.** Long explanation: The problem was my NHibernate mapping and how I was reusing RecipeLineItem variables to save new instances of Recipe to my database. In my code, I was using the same "lineItem1", "linItem2", "lineItem3", "lineItem4" etc variables to fill my Recipe variables' RecipeLineItems collection property. The problem with this is my NHibernate class mapping stated that there is only 1 RecipeLineItem to a Recipe (related by an Id field/property). Since my "lineItem'X'" variables all referred to the same memory instance of RecipeLineItem type, when I saved each Recipe to the database, NHibernate was writing over the previously saved Recipe's RecipeLineItems' Recipe_Id with the newly saved Recipe's Recipe_ID. So, my query was acting appropriately: there really was only one Recipe with a "Chocolate" RecipeLineItem. And it was always the last Recipe in my test list of Recipes because that was the last Recipe to overwrite the previous Recipe's line items. Sorry I couldn't word this any more succinctly. I hope it helps anyone else experiencing a similar problem.